# What's the equivalent of BP register ( Frame Pointer ) on ARM processors?

Tags: assembly, arm, calling-convention

On intel platforms, `BP` is used to point to the beginning of the stack frame and to access the arguments `[bp+0x??]` and local variables `[bp-0x??]`.

Which register is used in ARM? Or, is the addressing based on SP only?

[I don't have infrastructure to compile and disassemble to see it by myself. Referring to AAPCS did not help me either]

Comment: There is no equivalent for **AAPCS** (2003); the older **APCS** has R11 as an `FP` in ARM mode.  As ARM has more registers it is usually not needed to index locals via the stack/frame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Frame Pointer. Generally, `R7` acts as the frame pointer in THUMB mode and `R11` acts as the frame pointer in ARM mode. But it is under the discretion of the OS to change this convention if it wishes to.

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253599%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that this is an ABI issue, not a processor issue. (The processor doesn't care what register you use.) Different OSs can do things differently.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen. I updated my answer to reflect your (correct) views

Comment: ... and if you have a stack pointer register, modern compilers don't really need frame pointers  (FP); they know the layout of the stack and so can index from the SP to get anything they might have needed to access from the FP.  So a FP is really optional, depending on your compiler.

Comment: I don't know why the OS would have anything to do with this convention.  It might use a particular convention internally, but the applications shouldn't care; they only need to know the convention for *calling* OS primitives, and need only use that convention on such calls.  Otherwise they should be free to do pretty much as they like for calling/frame management conventions.

Comment: @RaymondChen To be very specific, isn't it the compiler's choice to choose a particular register as the Frame pointer rather than anything to do with the OS?

Comment: Some ABIs dictate a particular frame pointer register (so the OS can do stack walking).