# ARM: link register and frame pointer

Tags: c, arm

I'm trying to understand how the link register and the frame pointer work in ARM.  I've been to a couple of sites, and I wanted to confirm my understanding.

Suppose I had the following code:

```
int foo(void)
{
    // ..
    bar();
    // (A)
    // ..
}

int bar(void)
{
    // (B)
    int b1;
    // ..
    // (C)
    baz();
    // (D)
}

int baz(void)
{
    // (E)
    int a;
    int b;
    // (F)
}
```

and I call foo().  Would the link register contain the address for the code at point (A) and the frame pointer contain the address at the code at point (B)?  And the stack pointer would could be any where inside bar(), after all the locals have been declared?

Comment: I'm not sure what you might mean by "the stack pointer would could be any where inside bar()". Also, you seem to be asking about what the state of these things might be when `foo()` calls `bar()`, not when something calls `foo()` (but maybe I'm misunderstanding the question).

Comment: Yes, I meant the state of things when foo() calls bar().  What I meant regarding the SP was that the after the local have been declared and put on the stack, the SP will point at the top of the stack, where the last local variable was declared.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are SP (stack) and LR in ARM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236959/what-are-sp-stack-and-lr-in-arm)

Comment: Not a duplicate; SP != FP.  That link makes no mention of FP.

Comment: Yes, it is not a duplicate in the stack overflow sense.  It has relevant information.  The SP and FP are related, but not the same thing.  As well, the LR and PC are related but the question might not make a mention of them.  I do believe that viewers of that question will be wanting to understand function machinery.  Maybe I should have said 'relevant' instead of duplicate.  For certain the questions are related.

Comment: Following link gives more details about FP, how the assembly output will be when it is included and when it is not included (as flags) during compilation with an example. https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/arm-compilers-forum/4553/what-is-fp-r11-used-for#:~:text=the%20fp%20stands%20for%20the,of%20offsets%20for%20the%20stack.

Comment: @vijayanand1231  The link you supplied really does not explain anything better than what is here.  The difference you noted is embodied in APCS versus AAPCS.  The ARM link  is only giving some details for gcc (which not everyone uses).  Also, if people are struggling to understand what `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` means, they should give up.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Some register calling conventions are dependent on the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (Application Binary Interface).  The `FP` is required in the **APCS** standard and not in the newer **AAPCS** (2003). For the **AAPCS** (GCC 5.0+) the `FP` does not **have** to be used but certainly can be; [debug info is annotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451208/whats-the-structure-of-arm-extab-entry-in-armcc) with stack and frame pointer use for stack tracing and unwinding code with the **AAPCS**.  If a function is `static`, a compiler really doesn't have to adhere to any conventions.

Generally all ARM registers are *general purpose*.  The `lr` (link register, also R14) and `pc` (program counter also R15) are special and enshrine in the instruction set.  You are correct that the `lr` would point to **A**.   The `pc` and `lr` are related.  One is "where you are" and the other is "where you were".  They are the **code** aspect of a function.

Typically, we have the `sp` (stack pointer, R13) and the `fp` ([frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928646/whats-the-equivalent-of-bp-register-frame-pointer-on-arm-processors), R11).  These two are also related.  This 
[Microsoft layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253599%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does a good job describing things.  The *stack* is used to store temporary data or *locals* in your function.  Any variables in `foo()` and `bar()`, are stored here, *on the stack* or in available registers.  The `fp` keeps track of the variables from function to function.  It is a *frame* or picture window on the stack for that function.  The *ABI* defines a layout of this *frame*.  Typically the `lr` and other registers are saved here behind the scenes by the compiler as well as the previous value of `fp`.  This makes a *linked list* of stack frames and if you want you can trace it all the way back to `main()`.  The *root* is `fp`, which points to one stack frame (like a `struct`) with one variable in the `struct` being the previous `fp`.  You can go along the list until the final `fp` which is normally `NULL`.

So the `sp` is where the stack is and the `fp` is where the stack was, a lot like the `pc` and `lr`.  Each old `lr` (link register) is stored in the old `fp` (frame pointer).  The `sp` and `fp` are a **data** aspect of functions.

Your point **B** is the active `pc` and `sp`.  Point **A** is actually the `fp` and `lr`; unless you call yet another function and then the compiler might get ready to setup the `fp` to point to the data in **B**.

Following is some ARM assembler that might demonstrate how this all works.  This will be different depending on how the compiler optimizes, but it should give an idea,

```
; Prologue - setup
mov     ip, sp                 ; get a copy of sp.
stmdb   sp!, {fp, ip, lr, pc}  ; Save the frame on the stack. See Addendum
sub     fp, ip, #4             ; Set the new frame pointer.
    ...
; Maybe other functions called here.

; Older caller return lr stored in stack frame.
bl      baz
    ...
; Epilogue - return
ldm     sp, {fp, sp, lr}       ; restore stack, frame pointer and old link.
    ...                        ; maybe more stuff here.
bx      lr                     ; return.
```

This is what `foo()` would look like.  If you don't call `bar()`, then the compiler does a *leaf optimization* and doesn't need to save the *frame*; only the `bx lr` is needed.  Most likely this maybe why you are confused by web examples.  It is not always the same.

The take-away should be,

1. `pc` and `lr` are related **code** registers.  One is "Where you are", the other is "Where you were".
2. `sp` and `fp` are related **local data** registers.
   One is "Where local data is", the other is "Where the last local data is".
3. The work together along with [parameter passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save) to create *function* machinery.
4. It is hard to describe a general case because we want compilers to be as **fast** as possible, so they use every trick they can.

These concepts are generic to all CPUs and compiled languages, although the details can vary.  The use of the *link register*, *frame pointer* are part of the [function prologue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) and epilogue, and if you understood everything, you know how a *stack overflow* works on an ARM.

See also: [ARM calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save).
                [MSDN ARM stack article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448593.aspx)
                [University of Cambridge APCS overview](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/teaching/2001-02/arm-project/02-sort/apcs.txt)
                [ARM stack trace blog](http://minghuasweblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/arm-cc-software-stack-back-trace/)
                [Apple ABI link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARMv6FunctionCallingConventions.html)

The basic frame layout is,

- fp[-0] saved `pc`, where we stored this frame.
- fp[-1] saved `lr`, the return address for this function.
- fp[-2] previous `sp`, before this function *eats* stack.
- fp[-3] previous `fp`, the last *stack frame*.
- many optional registers...

An **ABI** may use other values, but the above are typical for most setups.  The indexes above are for 32 bit values as all ARM registers are 32 bits.  If you are byte-centric, multiply by four.  The frame is also aligned to at least four bytes.

**Addendum:**  This is not an error in the assembler; it is normal.  An explanation is in the [ARM generated prologs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623597/arm-gcc-generated-functions-prolog) question.

Comment: Ok, `lr` is where the code was, and `fp` is where the stack was.  This means that if I had another function `baz()`, `sp` would be at point (F) because the stack pointer was moved to allocate variables `a` and `b` inside `baz()`; `fp` be at point (E) because `sp` was at the top of `baz()`; and `lr` would be at (D)?

Comment: I updated the answer.  Instead of labels, it might be better to clarify.  When in `baz()`, sp would point to `baz()` data.  `pc` is `baz()` code.  The `fp` points to stuff to restore `bar()` context both code and data **OR** old `sp` and old `lr`==`foo()` return.  `lr` is the return to `bar()`, unless `baz()` calls more functions then the compiler must save `lr` in another stack frame because the call will destroy `lr`.

Comment: This is making sense.  The current active `lr` contains the address to return to in the previous stack frame (it's "where you were").  The active `fp` is an address within the current stack frame.  `fp`, `lr`, and `ip` are saved onto the stack before the branch to a new function.  When you do `bx lr` you return to the previous stack frame.  But then in your code, shouldn't you be restoring `lr` from the stack after the `bx lr` since `lr` already contains where you need to return to?  Otherwise, you would branch to the previous-previous stack frame.

Comment: Whoa, I should have said the `lr` contains the address of the code, from the previous function call, to return to **not** the address to return to in the previous stack frame.  `lr` points to somewhere in the text segment while `fp` points to somewhere in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I think this is roughly right; please correct as needed.

As indicated elsewhere in this Q&A, be aware that the compiler may not be required to generate (ABI) code that uses frame pointers. Frames on the call stack can often require useless information to be put there.

If the compiler options call for 'no frames' (a pseudo option flag), then the compiler can generate smaller code that keeps call stack data smaller. The calling function is compiled to only store the needed calling info on the stack, and the called function is compiled to only pop the needed calling information from the stack.

This saves execution time and stack space - but it makes tracing backwards in the calling code extremely hard (I gave up trying to...)

Info about the size and shape of the calling information on the stack is only known by the compiler and that info was thrown away after compile time.

Comment: This is mainly correct.  The `fp` can be used as a general register as well; this is a large benefit for some functions as they might not need to use stack.  You need two tables that are generated by the compiler to do stack tracing with the newer AAPCS.  I gave [ARM extab QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451208/whats-the-structure-of-arm-extab-entry-in-armcc) as a reference for this.