# get the caller's lr from subroutine into C variable - arm

Tags: assembly, arm

I've got a C function that's supposed to get the value of the caller's lr register into a local variable.

I've tried the following code:

```
volatile long lr;
asm(
    "str %0, [sp, #4]\n" :
    "=r", (lr)
);
```

However, this doesn't change anything. It's not that I get the wrong value, it's just that the value of the lr local variable doesn't change at all ( contains garbage ).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question directly, there are two solutions.

```
    long lr;
    asm(" mov %0,lr\n" :: "=r" (lr));
```

This will put the `lr` value in the *lr variable*.  You may wish to do this to analyse something.  If you are assuming that the `lr` contains a return address, then this is untrue as [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422797/igor-skochinsky) explains.  In a *non-leaf* function, the compiler may use the `lr` as a temporary when computing a function argument as it is going to be clobbered.

```
    register long lr asm("lr");
```

This form allows you to reference the variable *lr* anywhere and the compiler will use the live `lr` value.  The value may change through-out the function.  For instance, when you call another function, it will usually be set to the return point in the currently active function.

As [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422797/igor-skochinsky) explains whether getting the `lr` may not give you exactly what you expect.  And the mechanism's we are using are *gcc* specific.  You can not do this in a *portable* way; but accessing an `lr` is intrinsically non-portable.

See: [ARM link register and frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer) question for a little more on the use of `lr`.

Comment: As you are trying to access the APCS's *stack frame's* saved `lr`, I guess what you really want is the `__built_in_return_address()`; You would be better off to use the `fp` in this case, as it is always active.  The `sp` will be adjusted for local variables and will never be setup properly to get the saved `lr`.  You don't have to understand this at all if you use the `__built_in_return_address()`.

Comment: Also the newer AAPCS does not mandate a frame pointer be set up and so you need to use ancillary tables in ELF/object files to do a call tree walk (and for object clean up).  It is better to let `__built_in_return_address()` do this for you.  See [`-mabi`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) values which may affect `lr` use.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Your code will get the value at the address `SP+4`. Whether that location contains the initial `LR` depends on the compiler, optimization settings, specific function, or the place in the function where you put this code. In short, it would probably work only by accident.</strike>

**EDIT**: your code is not even *reading* anything relevant, it's just storing a value of uninitialized variable on the stack (hint: naming your variable `lr` doesn't make it magically take the value of the *register* `LR`). In the best case it won't do anything, in the worst you'll overwrite something important and it will crash.

I'll assume that you actually want to get the function's *return address*, not LR specifically. There exist compiler-specific options for that.

1. GCC offers the [`__builtin_return_address()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) intrinsic which returns the return address of the current function (if called with 0) or, possibly, other functions in the call stack (though I wouldn't rely on the latter).
2. Visual C++ has [`_ReturnAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64ez38eh) and even [`_AddressOfReturnAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7k) intrinsics.

I would recommend using one of the above (assuming you're using GCC or VC) and not rely on tricks which may stop working at any time.

Comment: _"Your code will get the value at the address SP+4"_ Will it? The OP is doing an `STR`, not `LDR`.

Comment: Oops, indeed. Then it's even more useless.