# Is it possible to access CPU registers such as LR, PC

Tags: c, assembly, arm, stm32

It is possible to access Sp, Lr, and Pc and store them in normal C variable?... if yes then how to do it.? please explain it with c code..

I'm using arm gcc compiler

Comment: You haven't specified which C compiler you're using.

Comment: Sure, with inline assembly or a call to a separate assembly function you can get any register value you want. How meaningful they are is another matter - `pc` and `sp` wouldn't tell much more than you can already know from C (take the address of a local variable or the current function), and apart from at the very start of a function `r14` could have _anything_ in it - 99 times out of 100 when people want to inspect `lr`, it means they really want their C compiler's `return_address` intrinsic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the caller's lr from subroutine into C variable - arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270702/get-the-callers-lr-from-subroutine-into-c-variable-arm)

Answer (score 4):

In GCC:

```
uint32_t some_variable;
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %0, lr" : "=r" (some_variable));
```

This tells the compiler to allocate a register for `some_variable` (which is represented by the placeholder `%0`), and then emit the instruction `mov %0, lr`. The effect is to store the value of `lr` into `some_variable`.

`__volatile__` tells the compiler not to reorder this instruction, which I assume you want.

This should also work with `pc` or `sp`. (Or any other register, but doing it with "normal" registers won't be very useful - among other things, the compiler might choose to allocate `some_variable` to the register you're trying to look at)

Comment: It might be not very useful to access any other register. But if the compiler allocates the register in question as the target of the `move` it would have still the correct value.