# Stack Backtrace for ARM core using GCC compiler (when there is a MSP to PSP switch)

Tags: gcc, arm, stack-trace, freertos

Core - ARM Cortex-M4

Compiler - GCC 5.3.0 ARM EABI

OS - Free RTOS

I am doing stack backtrace using gcc library function _Unwind_Reason_Code _Unwind_Backtrace(_Unwind_Trace_Fn,void*);

In our project, MSP stack is used for exception handling. In other cases, PSP stack is used. When I call _Unwind_Backtrace() inside the exception handler, I am able to back trace properly up to the first function which is called inside exception. Until this the stack is MSP.

But before exception, we were not able to back trace. At this point, the stack used is PSP.

For eg: Assume

```
Task1
{
    func1()
}



func1
{
  func2()
}

func2
{
  an exception occurs here
}

**Inside Exception**
{
  func1ex()
}

func1ex
{
   func2ex()
}



func2ex
{
  unwind backtrace()
}
```

Unwind backtrace is able to backtrace up to func1ex() but not able to backtrace the path task1-->func1-->func2

Because there is a switching between PSP to MSP stack during exception, it is not able to backtrace functions which are using PSP.

Before control comes to exception handler, registers R0, R1, R2, R3, LR, PC and XPSR are stacked in the PSP by the core. I am able to view that. But I don't know how to use this stack frame to do backtrace for PSP.

Could anybody tell what to do in this case such that we can backtrace up to task level?

Thanks,

Ashwin.

Comment: In the above comment, I am using the following compiler options  -funwind-tables \
-fexceptions \
-mtpcs-frame \
-mtpcs-leaf-frame \
-fno-omit-frame-pointer \
-fno-optimize-sibling-calls..Language used is C.

Answer (score 4):

This is doable but needs access to internal details of how libgcc implements the _Unwind_Backtrace function. Fortunately the code is open-source, but depending on such internal details is brittle in that it may break in future versions of armgcc without any notice.

Generally, reading through the source of libgcc doing the backtrace, it creates an inmemory virtual representation of the CPU core registers, then uses this representation to walk up the stack, simulating exception throws. The first thing that _Unwind_Backtrace does is fill in this context from the current CPU registers, then call an internal implementation function.

Creating that context manually from the stacked exception structure is sufficient to fake the backtrace going from handler mode upwards through the call stack in most cases. Here is some example code (from https://github.com/bakerstu/openmrn/blob/62683863e8621cef35e94c9dcfe5abcaf996d7a2/src/freertos_drivers/common/cpu_profile.hxx#L162):

```
/// This struct definition mimics the internal structures of libgcc in
/// arm-none-eabi binary. It's not portable and might break in the future.
struct core_regs
{
    unsigned r[16];
};

/// This struct definition mimics the internal structures of libgcc in
/// arm-none-eabi binary. It's not portable and might break in the future.
typedef struct
{
    unsigned demand_save_flags;
    struct core_regs core;
} phase2_vrs;

/// We store what we know about the external context at interrupt entry in this
/// structure.
phase2_vrs main_context;
/// Saved value of the lr register at the exception entry.
unsigned saved_lr;

/// Takes registers from the core state and the saved exception context and
/// fills in the structure necessary for the LIBGCC unwinder.
void fill_phase2_vrs(volatile unsigned *fault_args)
{
    main_context.demand_save_flags = 0;
    main_context.core.r[0] = fault_args[0];
    main_context.core.r[1] = fault_args[1];
    main_context.core.r[2] = fault_args[2];
    main_context.core.r[3] = fault_args[3];
    main_context.core.r[12] = fault_args[4];
    // We add +2 here because first thing libgcc does with the lr value is
    // subtract two, presuming that lr points to after a branch
    // instruction. However, exception entry's saved PC can point to the first
    // instruction of a function and we don't want to have the backtrace end up
    // showing the previous function.
    main_context.core.r[14] = fault_args[6] + 2;
    main_context.core.r[15] = fault_args[6];
    saved_lr = fault_args[5];
    main_context.core.r[13] = (unsigned)(fault_args + 8); // stack pointer
}
extern "C"
{
    _Unwind_Reason_Code __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace(
        _Unwind_Trace_Fn trace, void *trace_argument, phase2_vrs *entry_vrs);
}

/// Static variable for trace_func.
void *last_ip;

/// Callback from the unwind backtrace function.
_Unwind_Reason_Code trace_func(struct _Unwind_Context *context, void *arg)
{
    void *ip;
    ip = (void *)_Unwind_GetIP(context);
    if (strace_len == 0)
    {
        // stacktrace[strace_len++] = ip;
        // By taking the beginning of the function for the immediate interrupt
        // we will attempt to coalesce more traces.
        // ip = (void *)_Unwind_GetRegionStart(context);
    }
    else if (last_ip == ip)
    {
        if (strace_len == 1 && saved_lr != _Unwind_GetGR(context, 14))
        {
            _Unwind_SetGR(context, 14, saved_lr);
            allocator.singleLenHack++;
            return _URC_NO_REASON;
        }
        return _URC_END_OF_STACK;
    }
    if (strace_len >= MAX_STRACE - 1)
    {
        ++allocator.limitReached;
        return _URC_END_OF_STACK;
    }
    // stacktrace[strace_len++] = ip;
    last_ip = ip;
    ip = (void *)_Unwind_GetRegionStart(context);
    stacktrace[strace_len++] = ip;
    return _URC_NO_REASON;
}

/// Called from the interrupt handler to take a CPU trace for the current
/// exception.
void take_cpu_trace()
{
    memset(stacktrace, 0, sizeof(stacktrace));
    strace_len = 0;
    last_ip = nullptr;
    phase2_vrs first_context = main_context;
    __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace(&trace_func, 0, &first_context);
    // This is a workaround for the case when the function in which we had the
    // exception trigger does not have a stack saved LR. In this case the
    // backtrace will fail after the first step. We manually append the second
    // step to have at least some idea of what's going on.
    if (strace_len == 1)
    {
        main_context.core.r[14] = saved_lr;
        main_context.core.r[15] = saved_lr;
        __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace(&trace_func, 0, &main_context);
    }
    unsigned h = hash_trace(strace_len, (unsigned *)stacktrace);
    struct trace *t = find_current_trace(h);
    if (!t)
    {
        t = add_new_trace(h);
    }
    if (t)
    {
        t->total_size += 1;
    }
}

/// Change this value to runtime disable and enable the CPU profile gathering
/// code.
bool enable_profiling = 0;

/// Helper function to declare the CPU usage tick interrupt.
/// @param irq_handler_name is the name of the interrupt to declare, for example
/// timer4a_interrupt_handler.
/// @param CLEAR_IRQ_FLAG is a c++ statement or statements in { ... } that will
/// be executed before returning from the interrupt to clear the timer IRQ flag.
#define DEFINE_CPU_PROFILE_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(irq_handler_name, CLEAR_IRQ_FLAG) \
    extern "C"                                                                 \
    {                                                                          \
        void __attribute__((__noinline__)) load_monitor_interrupt_handler(     \
            volatile unsigned *exception_args, unsigned exception_return_code) \
        {                                                                      \
            if (enable_profiling)                                              \
            {                                                                  \
                fill_phase2_vrs(exception_args);                               \
                take_cpu_trace();                                              \
            }                                                                  \
            cpuload_tick(exception_return_code & 4 ? 0 : 255);                 \
            CLEAR_IRQ_FLAG;                                                    \
        }                                                                      \
        void __attribute__((__naked__)) irq_handler_name(void)                 \
        {                                                                      \
            __asm volatile("mov  r0, %0 \n"                                    \
                           "str  r4, [r0, 4*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r5, [r0, 5*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r6, [r0, 6*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r7, [r0, 7*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r8, [r0, 8*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r9, [r0, 9*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r10, [r0, 10*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r11, [r0, 11*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r12, [r0, 12*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r13, [r0, 13*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r14, [r0, 14*4] \n"                           \
                           :                                                   \
                           : "r"(main_context.core.r)                          \
                           : "r0");                                            \
            __asm volatile(" tst   lr, #4               \n"                    \
                           " ite   eq                   \n"                    \
                           " mrseq r0, msp              \n"                    \
                           " mrsne r0, psp              \n"                    \
                           " mov r1, lr \n"                                    \
                           " ldr r2,  =load_monitor_interrupt_handler  \n"     \
                           " bx  r2  \n"                                       \
                           :                                                   \
                           :                                                   \
                           : "r0", "r1", "r2");                                \
        }                                                                      \
    }
```

This code is designed to take a CPU profile using a timer interrupt, but the backtrace unwinding can be reused from any handler including fault handlers. Read the code from the bottom to the top:

- It is important that the IRQ function be defined with the attribute `__naked__`, otherwise the function entry header of GCC will manipulate the state of the CPU in unpredictable way, modifying the stack pointer for example.
- First thing we save all other core registers that are not in the exception entry struct. We need to do this from assembly right at the beginning, because these will be typically modified by later C code when they are used as temporary registers.
- Then we reconstruct the stack pointer from before the interrupt; the code will work whether the processor was in handler or thread mode before. This pointer is the exception entry structure. This code does not handle stacks that are not 4-byte aligned, but I never saw armgcc do that anyway.
- The rest of the code is in C/C++, we fill in the internal structure we took from libgcc, then call the internal implementation of the unwinding process. There are some adjustments we need to make to work around certain assumptions of libgcc that do not hold upon exception entry.
- There is one specific situation where the unwinding does not work, which is if the exception happened in a leaf function that does not save LR to the stack upon entry. This never happens when you try to do a backtrace from process mode, because the backtrace function being called will ensure that the calling function is not a leaf. I tried to apply some workarounds by adjusting the LR register during the backtracing process itself, but I'm not convinced it works every time. I'm interested in suggestions on how to do this better.