# _Unwind_Backtrace for different context on FreeRTOS

Tags: error-handling, embedded, freertos, libunwind

Hello I am trying to implement error handling in FreeRTOS project. The handler is triggered by WatchDog interrupt, prior to WatchDog reset. The idea is to log task name + call stack of the failed task.
I have managed to backtrace a call stack but in the wrong context, the context of the interrupt. While I need the context of the failed task which is stored in pxCurrentTCB. but I do not know how to tell _Unwind_Backtrace to use it instead of the interrupt context, where it is called from.
So I want to _Unwind_Backtrace not the context it is called from but for different context found in pxCurrentTCB. I have searched and tried to understand how _Unwind_Backtrace work but without success, so please help.
Any help will be appreciated especially sample code. Thank you.

```
_Unwind_Reason_Code unwind_backtrace_callback(_Unwind_Context * context, void * arg)
{
    static uint8_t row = 1;
    char str_buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    uintptr_t pc = _Unwind_GetIP(context);
    if (pc && row < MAX_ROW) {
        snprintf(str_buff, sizeof(str_buff), "%d .. 0x%x", row, pc);
        printString(str_buff, 0, ROW_SIZE * row++);
    }
    return _URC_NO_REASON;
}

void WDOG1_DriverIRQHandler(void)
{
    printString(pxCurrentTCB->pcTaskName, 0, 0);

    _Unwind_Backtrace(unwind_backtrace_callback, 0);

    while(1) Wdog_Service();
}
```

Comment: Info + better explanation of the problem. It is still unresolved.
[link](https://html.developreference.com/article/13326864/Stack+Backtrace+for+ARM+core+using+GCC+compiler+(when+there+is+a+MSP+to+PSP+switch))
[link](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-m-forum/43660/can-i-change-sp-at-run-time-in-cm33?ReplySortBy=CreatedDate&ReplySortOrder=Ascending)

Comment: You should be able to edit your question yourself, refining the information with the links you put in the comment etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, OpenMRN implements exactly the solution you are looking for: https://github.com/bakerstu/openmrn/blob/master/src/freertos_drivers/common/cpu_profile.hxx

More information can be found here: [Stack Backtrace for ARM core using GCC compiler (when there is a MSP to PSP switch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331426/stack-backtrace-for-arm-core-using-gcc-compiler-when-there-is-a-msp-to-psp-swit/50923698#50923698). To quote this post:

> This is doable but needs access to internal details of how libgcc implements the _Unwind_Backtrace function. Fortunately the code is open-source, but depending on such internal details is brittle in that it may break in future versions of armgcc without any notice.
>
> Generally, reading through the source of libgcc doing the backtrace, it creates an inmemory virtual representation of the CPU core registers, then uses this representation to walk up the stack, simulating exception throws. The first thing that _Unwind_Backtrace does is fill in this context from the current CPU registers, then call an internal implementation function.
>
> Creating that context manually from the stacked exception structure is sufficient to fake the backtrace going from handler mode upwards through the call stack in most cases. Here is some example code (from https://github.com/bakerstu/openmrn/blob/62683863e8621cef35e94c9dcfe5abcaf996d7a2/src/freertos_drivers/common/cpu_profile.hxx#L162):

```
/// This struct definition mimics the internal structures of libgcc in
/// arm-none-eabi binary. It's not portable and might break in the future.
struct core_regs
{
    unsigned r[16];
};

/// This struct definition mimics the internal structures of libgcc in
/// arm-none-eabi binary. It's not portable and might break in the future.
typedef struct
{
    unsigned demand_save_flags;
    struct core_regs core;
} phase2_vrs;

/// We store what we know about the external context at interrupt entry in this
/// structure.
phase2_vrs main_context;
/// Saved value of the lr register at the exception entry.
unsigned saved_lr;

/// Takes registers from the core state and the saved exception context and
/// fills in the structure necessary for the LIBGCC unwinder.
void fill_phase2_vrs(volatile unsigned *fault_args)
{
    main_context.demand_save_flags = 0;
    main_context.core.r[0] = fault_args[0];
    main_context.core.r[1] = fault_args[1];
    main_context.core.r[2] = fault_args[2];
    main_context.core.r[3] = fault_args[3];
    main_context.core.r[12] = fault_args[4];
    // We add +2 here because first thing libgcc does with the lr value is
    // subtract two, presuming that lr points to after a branch
    // instruction. However, exception entry's saved PC can point to the first
    // instruction of a function and we don't want to have the backtrace end up
    // showing the previous function.
    main_context.core.r[14] = fault_args[6] + 2;
    main_context.core.r[15] = fault_args[6];
    saved_lr = fault_args[5];
    main_context.core.r[13] = (unsigned)(fault_args + 8); // stack pointer
}
extern "C"
{
    _Unwind_Reason_Code __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace(
        _Unwind_Trace_Fn trace, void *trace_argument, phase2_vrs *entry_vrs);
}

/// Static variable for trace_func.
void *last_ip;

/// Callback from the unwind backtrace function.
_Unwind_Reason_Code trace_func(struct _Unwind_Context *context, void *arg)
{
    void *ip;
    ip = (void *)_Unwind_GetIP(context);
    if (strace_len == 0)
    {
        // stacktrace[strace_len++] = ip;
        // By taking the beginning of the function for the immediate interrupt
        // we will attempt to coalesce more traces.
        // ip = (void *)_Unwind_GetRegionStart(context);
    }
    else if (last_ip == ip)
    {
        if (strace_len == 1 && saved_lr != _Unwind_GetGR(context, 14))
        {
            _Unwind_SetGR(context, 14, saved_lr);
            allocator.singleLenHack++;
            return _URC_NO_REASON;
        }
        return _URC_END_OF_STACK;
    }
    if (strace_len >= MAX_STRACE - 1)
    {
        ++allocator.limitReached;
        return _URC_END_OF_STACK;
    }
    // stacktrace[strace_len++] = ip;
    last_ip = ip;
    ip = (void *)_Unwind_GetRegionStart(context);
    stacktrace[strace_len++] = ip;
    return _URC_NO_REASON;
}

/// Called from the interrupt handler to take a CPU trace for the current
/// exception.
void take_cpu_trace()
{
    memset(stacktrace, 0, sizeof(stacktrace));
    strace_len = 0;
    last_ip = nullptr;
    phase2_vrs first_context = main_context;
    __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace(&trace_func, 0, &first_context);
    // This is a workaround for the case when the function in which we had the
    // exception trigger does not have a stack saved LR. In this case the
    // backtrace will fail after the first step. We manually append the second
    // step to have at least some idea of what's going on.
    if (strace_len == 1)
    {
        main_context.core.r[14] = saved_lr;
        main_context.core.r[15] = saved_lr;
        __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace(&trace_func, 0, &main_context);
    }
    unsigned h = hash_trace(strace_len, (unsigned *)stacktrace);
    struct trace *t = find_current_trace(h);
    if (!t)
    {
        t = add_new_trace(h);
    }
    if (t)
    {
        t->total_size += 1;
    }
}

/// Change this value to runtime disable and enable the CPU profile gathering
/// code.
bool enable_profiling = 0;

/// Helper function to declare the CPU usage tick interrupt.
/// @param irq_handler_name is the name of the interrupt to declare, for example
/// timer4a_interrupt_handler.
/// @param CLEAR_IRQ_FLAG is a c++ statement or statements in { ... } that will
/// be executed before returning from the interrupt to clear the timer IRQ flag.
#define DEFINE_CPU_PROFILE_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(irq_handler_name, CLEAR_IRQ_FLAG) \
    extern "C"                                                                 \
    {                                                                          \
        void __attribute__((__noinline__)) load_monitor_interrupt_handler(     \
            volatile unsigned *exception_args, unsigned exception_return_code) \
        {                                                                      \
            if (enable_profiling)                                              \
            {                                                                  \
                fill_phase2_vrs(exception_args);                               \
                take_cpu_trace();                                              \
            }                                                                  \
            cpuload_tick(exception_return_code & 4 ? 0 : 255);                 \
            CLEAR_IRQ_FLAG;                                                    \
        }                                                                      \
        void __attribute__((__naked__)) irq_handler_name(void)                 \
        {                                                                      \
            __asm volatile("mov  r0, %0 \n"                                    \
                           "str  r4, [r0, 4*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r5, [r0, 5*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r6, [r0, 6*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r7, [r0, 7*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r8, [r0, 8*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r9, [r0, 9*4] \n"                             \
                           "str  r10, [r0, 10*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r11, [r0, 11*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r12, [r0, 12*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r13, [r0, 13*4] \n"                           \
                           "str  r14, [r0, 14*4] \n"                           \
                           :                                                   \
                           : "r"(main_context.core.r)                          \
                           : "r0");                                            \
            __asm volatile(" tst   lr, #4               \n"                    \
                           " ite   eq                   \n"                    \
                           " mrseq r0, msp              \n"                    \
                           " mrsne r0, psp              \n"                    \
                           " mov r1, lr \n"                                    \
                           " ldr r2,  =load_monitor_interrupt_handler  \n"     \
                           " bx  r2  \n"                                       \
                           :                                                   \
                           :                                                   \
                           : "r0", "r1", "r2");                                \
        }                                                                      \
    }
```

> This code is designed to take a CPU profile using a timer interrupt, but the backtrace unwinding can be reused from any handler including fault handlers. Read the code from the bottom to the top:
>
> - It is important that the IRQ function be defined with the attribute `__naked__`, otherwise the function entry header of GCC will manipulate the state of the CPU in unpredictable way, modifying the stack pointer for example.
> - First thing we save all other core registers that are not in the exception entry struct. We need to do this from assembly right at the beginning, because these will be typically modified by later C code when they are used as temporary registers.
> - Then we reconstruct the stack pointer from before the interrupt; the code will work whether the processor was in handler or thread mode before. This pointer is the exception entry structure. This code does not handle stacks that are not 4-byte aligned, but I never saw armgcc do that anyway.
> - The rest of the code is in C/C++, we fill in the internal structure we took from libgcc, then call the internal implementation of the unwinding process. There are some adjustments we need to make to work around certain assumptions of libgcc that do not hold upon exception entry.
> - There is one specific situation where the unwinding does not work, which is if the exception happened in a leaf function that does not save LR to the stack upon entry. This never happens when you try to do a backtrace from process mode, because the backtrace function being called will ensure that the calling function is not a leaf. I tried to apply some workarounds by adjusting the LR register during the backtracing process itself, but I'm not convinced it works every time. I'm interested in suggestions on how to do this better.

Comment: Consider adding more detail to this post instead of just URLs. Eventually all URLs will change or go offline, at which point this answer will not provide very much useful information to future visitors.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying the same thing, unfortunately without success.
In my case, it seems like the `_Unwind_Backtrace` function does not call the trace function internally. In addition, I always receive the return code `_URC_FAILURE(9)`. I am using the `arm-none-eabi-gcc (Arch Repository) 13.2.0` compiler with an STM32WB55 chip.

Does somebody know how to fix the `_Unwind_Backtrace` function?