# How Do I protect r14 register in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to ARM assembly and reading about BL instruction which says

The BL and BLX instructions copy the address of the next instruction into lr(r14).

Address of next instruction is stored in r14 and Now,how Do I make sure that no other program or routine should use this register.

How Do I protect r14 from not overwritten by some other routine??

Comment: possible duplicate of [ARM: link register and frame pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is going to call another function (or use r14 as a gpr) then push it on the stack upon entry in the function (or at least before you modify it) and then restore it at some point before you return.

```
stmdb r13!,{lr}
...
bl somefunction
...
ldmia r13!,{pc}
```

If you are mixing C and assembly or any compiled code, then you should try to conform to the arm eabi, which now wants the stack 64 bit aligned so push another register, doesnt matter if you need to or not, so that you have an even number of registers being pushed and popped.

Comment: Yes @dwelch ,it is something like we used to do in x86 ,callee save convention.

Comment: it is a target independent solution/convention.  Use the stack to preserve local (function, scope) information.

Answer (score 2):

If you're programming in assembly, what is this "other program or routine" you're so afraid of?

Are you calling other people's code? If you are, then the standard ARM calling conventions should apply, and the fact that the LR register is used for linkage is well-known. In your own code, simply make sure you don't try to use the register for anything else, or save it first if you do.

Comment: Thanks @unwind .I was just thinking in virtula multicore environment where multiple core comes up at same time.there are any chances for r14 to be overwritten.

Comment: Of course other cores have their own execution state (otherwise, how could you reliably program anything at all?) If you are writing a threaded program you generally have to be concerned about the state of globally visible memory, but not registers or memory that is only used locally.