# When is .ARM.exidx is used

Tags: arm, stm32, linker-scripts, contiki, codesourcery

I am working on Contiki 2.7 with the mbxxx target. While building my code the linker complained about an **overlap of .ARM.exidx and .data sections**. After some tinkering around with the linker script contiki-2.7/cpu/stm32w108/gnu-stm32w108.ld I fixed the problem by replacing:

```
__exidx_start = .;
__exidx_end = .;
```

with:

```
.ARM.exidx : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    __exidx_end = .;
} >ROM_region
```

Later when I tried to see the header listing of some other example applications by using `objdump -h` I did not find this particular *.ARM.exidx* section, while it is present in my application. Googling about *.ARM.exidx* led me to the fact that it is used for some c++ exception handling. Since my code is a pure C code, why is this section present on my code? When is generally *.ARM.exidx* present in code and what is its utility?

---

Well no, I don't have any such compiler options. I am actually using the AxTLS api and ripped out the certificate handling code and ported it to contiki. On some further digging I found a fishy behaviour in the bigint implementation. To be brief... here is the body of a function from the bigint.c file:

```
static bigint *bi_int_multiply(BI_CTX *ctx, bigint *bia, comp b)
{
   int j = 0, n = bia->size;
   bigint *biR = alloc(ctx, n + 1);
   comp carry = 5;
   comp *r = biR->comps;
   comp *a = bia->comps;

   check(bia);

   /* clear things to start with */
   memset(r, 0, ((n+1)*COMP_BYTE_SIZE));


   do
   {
       long_comp tmp = *r + (long_comp)a[j]*b + carry;
   //    *r++ = (comp)tmp;              /* downsize */
       carry = (comp)(tmp >> COMP_BIT_SIZE);
   } while (++j < n);

  // *r = carry;
  bi_free(ctx, bia);

  return trim(biR);
}
```

If the commented out portions, (the r variable assignment) is uncommented, the *.ARM.exidx* thingy appears, otherwise it doesn't! Now can this be explained?

---

I didn't find anything out of the ordinary used in the implementation of `alloc()`. There were 2 references of `alloca()` used in some separate region of the code, which I replaced with `malloc()` and `free()`, but that didn't fix the problem either. `alloc()` implementation has only calls to `malloc()`,`realloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Hello @user2668988! Just as a heads up, if you want to add more detail to your question, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21527256/edit) your question here.

Comment: Is `biR` using `alloca()` or how is `alloc()` implemented?  The compiler may use the same C++ mechanism to track `alloca()` type allocations.  When you comment out `r`, with optimizations, the `alloc()` won't happen.

Comment: I didn't find any thing out of the ordinary used in the implementation of `alloc()`. There were 2 references of `alloca()` used in some separate region of the code, which I replaced with `malloc()` and `free()`, but that didn't fix the problem either. `alloc()` implementation has only calls to `malloc()`,`realloc()` and `free()`

Answer (score 22):

`.ARM.exidx` is the section containing information for unwinding the stack. If your C program has functions that print out a stack backtrace, the functions will likely depend on this section being present.

Maybe look for a `-funwind-tables` or `-fexceptions` flag in your compiler options.

Comment: I believe the `-funwind-tables` option is on by default, at least in CodeSourcery toolchains of recent years. Without it, back-trace in the debugger is quite hard.

Comment: how to disable this option then?

Comment: Find the flag and remove it?

Comment: You cant "remove" implicit flag, but sometimes adding cointer flag is possible (like `-fno-unwind-tables`)

Answer (score 7):

This feature is used in 'C'.  The ARM APCS uses only a frame pointer to restore a stack.  The newer AAPCS uses tables on occasion.  Stack unwinding, signal handlers and other *asynchronous* 'C' features use these mechanism.  For a bare metal embedded device it can be used to trace a stack.  For instance, Linux's [unwind.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/unwind.c) uses both `exidx` and `extab` sections to do a stack trace.

Briefly the `exidx` is a sorted table of routine start addresses and an `extab` table index.  A binary search through the `exidx` will find the corresponding `extab` entry.  The `extab` entry has details about the stack **in this routine**<sup>Note1</sup>.  It gives details about what the routine is storing on the stack.

> if the commented out portions, (the r variable assignment) is uncommented, the .ARM.exidx thingy appears, otherwise it doesn't! Now can this be explained???

When you have the statement `*r++ = (comp)tmp;`, the compiler can not hold all the variables in registers and needs to use the stack (or at least `fp`).  This causes it to emit and `exidx` and `extab` data.

---

There are some solutions.  It is fine to discard both `exidx` and `extab` if you don't need stack tracing or asynchronous functionality.  Simpler stack unwinding can be done with gnu tools/gcc using `-mapcs-frame`; then `fp` will always be used to store the previous stack frame (which stores its callers `fp`, etc).  The actual tables are not that big and the routines to unwind are fairly simple.  It maybe <3% overhead to have the tables which don't pollute the normal program path or use a register like `-mapcs-frame`.  Desirable on Cortex-A cpus with cache and usually more memory.

Reference: [ATPCS Link and frame pointer explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer)
                  [Structure of ARM extab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451208/whats-the-structure-of-arm-extab-entry-in-armcc)

**Note1:** This is after the prologue makes an adjustment to the stack.
**Note2:** The `ex` is for exception, but it is not solely for C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to tangrs' response, if you gcc -v, you can dump the default options used during compilation.

All options (implicit & explicit) options of GCC are passed to cc1 program of GCC.