# What's the primary difference between branch instruction and branch with link instruction? ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, subroutine, function-call

From what I read, the branch with link is used to perform subroutine call and the registered link is copied back to PC.

Comment: The [ARM frame and link registers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer) question is related.  It is not a duplicate, but when you go one step beyond this question... it will be your next step in understanding the ARM function call mechanisms that compilers use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Branch with link `BL` copies the address of the next instruction (after the `BL`) into the link register. The branch instruction doesn't. `BL` would be used for a subroutine call, so when you want to return to where you were you can branch back to the link register.