# Interpretation of app c++ crash information?

Tags: android, c++, arm, cpu-registers, arm64

I deliberately wrote a code that triggers a null pointer crash，
got this crash log :

```
libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 27802 (sodino.demo), pid 27802 (sodino.demo)
DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-07-17 11:23:28+0800
DEBUG   : pid: 27802, tid: 27802, name: sodino.demo  >>> sodino.demo <<<
DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000018  x1  000000707e2e4998  x2  0000000000000019  x3  2073796173207070
DEBUG   :     x4  000000707e2e499e  x5  0000007077a70c58  x6  0000000062626161  x7  0000000063636262
DEBUG   :     x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000018
DEBUG   :     x12 6820737961732070  x13 206f74206f6c6c65  x14 0000000000000010  x15 000000711109f39a
DEBUG   :     x16 00000071110a4b58  x17 00000071110082bc  x18 0000007115812000  x19 000000708ee10800
DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000000  x21 000000708ee10800  x22 0000007fcf67f890  x23 0000007114845658
DEBUG   :     x24 0000000000000004  x25 000000711499c020  x26 000000708ee108b0  x27 0000000000000001
DEBUG   :     x28 0000007fcf67f620  x29 0000007fcf67f5c0
DEBUG   :     sp  0000007fcf67f560  lr  000000707e2cc9b8  pc  000000707e2cc9c8
DEBUG   : 
DEBUG   : backtrace:
DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000000c9c8  /data/app/sodino.demo-K1-uQOGzzG20SxiRS9-g1Q==/base.apk!libnative-lib.so (offset 0x1000) (concatenateMyStringWithCppString(char const*)+248) (BuildId: fdb041aba6818c49543f4b4e93c433f6d787c772)
DEBUG   :       #01 pc 000000000000c878  /data/app/sodino.demo-K1-uQOGzzG20SxiRS9-g1Q==/base.apk!libnative-lib.so (offset 0x1000) (Java_sodino_demo_MainActivity_stringFromJNI+32) (BuildId: fdb041aba6818c49543f4b4e93c433f6d787c772)
```

content in the middel of the log :

what is  `x0` ~ `x29` ?
what is `sp` `lr` `pc` ?

---

Second Question :

```
#00 pc 000000000000c9c8  
/data/app/sodino.demo-K1-uQOGzzG20SxiRS9-g1Q==/base.apk!
libnative-lib.so (offset 0x1000) 
(concatenateMyStringWithCppString(char const*)+248) 
(BuildId: fdb041aba6818c49543f4b4e93c433f6d787c772)
```

`(concatenateMyStringWithCppString(char const*)+248)`
what is meaning of `+248` ?

I thought `+248` was the code line number,
but the code did not match as below : `line 11` trigger the null point crash :

Core.h

```
#ifndef __HelloCpp__Core__
#define __HelloCpp__Core__

#include <iostream>

const char *concatenateMyStringWithCppString(const char *myString);

#endif /* defined(__HelloCpp__Core__) */
```

Core.cpp

```
#include <string.h>
#include "Core.h"

const char *CPP_BASE_STRING = "cpp says hello to %s";

const char *concatenateMyStringWithCppString(const char *myString) {
    char *concatenatedString = new char[strlen(CPP_BASE_STRING) + strlen(myString)];
    sprintf(concatenatedString, CPP_BASE_STRING, myString);

    char* p = NULL;
    *p = 0;                    // line 11 crash.
    return concatenatedString;
}
```

native-lib.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "Core.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_sodino_demo_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    const char* result = concatenateMyStringWithCppString("aabbcc");
//    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
return env->NewStringUTF(result);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using M1 based Mac. Those are Arm64 registers: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101/Registers-in-AArch64---general-purpose-registers#:~:text=Registers%20in%20AArch64%20%2D%20system%20registers,Data%20processing%20%2D%20extension%20and%20saturation `SP: stack pointer, pc: Program counter and LR: Link register` More: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/h/programmers-model/processor-core-register-summary

Comment: Oops I don't use Android but nevertheless they are called registers and those links should be helpful to you.

Comment: That number is an offset, you should post the relevant source code along with the arguments used to call that function rather than posting screenshot

Comment: @Asesh I edited again.

Comment: `sp`: Stack Pointer, `lr`: Link register (return address),  `pc`: program counter (current address of code), `x0`..`x29`: 64-bit general-purpose registers (arm64 arch)

Comment: backtrace is the `call stack` and `(concatenateMyStringWithCppString(char const*)+248)` means the address of `concatenateMyStringWithCppString(char const*)` plus 248 (as an offset).

Comment: You should read more about arm64 architecture to know its registers and their applications if you want more details. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/ARMv8-Registers/AArch64-special-registers

Answer (score 2):

> what is x0 ~ x29 ? what is sp lr pc?

The x0 to x29 are [general purpose registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) for the ARM64.
`sp`, `lr` and `pc` are as described in [ARM link and frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer).

- `sp` the stack pointer used for *local* data in a function.
- `lr` the return address of the function/method that called the current routine.
- `pc` the current instruction.

Registers are common to all commercial CPUs.  It is possible to make stack base only architectures, but they generally can not perform as well.  A compiler can recognize *hot* values and assign them to registers at build time.  Stack is generally 5-100x slower than registers.

---

```
(concatenateMyStringWithCppString(char const*)+248) 
(BuildId: fdb041aba6818c49543f4b4e93c433f6d787c772)
```

> what is meaning of +248 ?

This is not at the code level.  It is the number of instructions since the start of the routine `concatenateMyStringWithCppString`.  In fact, if all of the routines are not visible to the tracing code,the instruction could be in a different function.

The normal process is to get an assembler listing and it will be (248/4 -> 62) instructions after.  Without seeing the assembler,

```
const char *concatenateMyStringWithCppString(const char *myString) {
    char *concatenatedString = new char[strlen(CPP_BASE_STRING) + strlen(myString)];
    sprintf(concatenatedString, CPP_BASE_STRING, myString);

    char* p = NULL;
    *p = 0;                    // line 11 crash.
    return concatenatedString;
}
```

It looks like line 11 would be about 62 instructions into the routine, especially if `strlen()` is inlined.  Compiler options, versions, etc will change the offset versus line number as they generate different code.

Answer (score 1):

> what is [the] meaning of +248 ?

It looks like you don't have debug symbols in your binary. Try compiling and linking with `-g` flag, and you should see source file name and line number in stack traces.

In case of Android, this can be achieved by building with `NDK_DEBUG=1` or set `android:debuggable="true"` in the manifest. See [Debuggable versus release builds](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build#dvr) for more details.

When no debug symbols are available, debug backtraces contain addresses and approximate code locations using `function + offset` syntax. The offset (+248 in your example) is the address of the failing instruction relative to the start of the function.

---

> what is x0 ~ x29 ? what is sp lr pc?

Those are ARM64 registers. They provide additional details for advanced post-mortem analysis at assembly level. Using the source code in combination with the corresponding assembly and register values at the time of the fault, it's possible to back-track to the root cause of the fault. In your case it's not needed, since the root cause is obvious. In real-life crashes one often has to go up in the code path in order to understand where a null pointer came from.