# Implementing Quick Sort Algorithm in Visual2 with armv7

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm an engineering student. I have developed this recursive quick sort algorithm in Visual2 that works, but I still can't finish it because I should pop at the end of the subroutine all the registers I've stored at the start of the same one. Can anyone help me?
Furthermore I should find a way to stop the subroutine early if the length of the list is <=1.
You can find the code I've developed attached

```
          ;       INIZIO PROGRAMMA
          MOV     R0, #LIST ; Carico l'indirizzo di memoria di LEN
          STR     R0, [R13]

          MOV     R0, #LEN ; Carico l'indirizzo di memoria di LEN
          LDR     R0, [R0] ; Carico il valore dell'indirizzo di memoria
          STR     R0, [R13, #-4]!

          BL      QUICKSORT ; muovo il contenuto di PC in LR e salto a QUICKSORT
          END


          ;       SOTTOPROGRAMMA "QUICKSORT"
          ;       R0 = Registro che punta alla posizione assoluta del primo elemento della lista
          ;       R1 = Registro che indica la lunghezza della lista alla destra del pivot
          ;       R8 = Registro che indica la lunghezza della lista alla sinistra del pivot
          ;       R2 = Registro che serve per scorrere gli elementi della lista
          ;       R3 = Registro che indica la posizione relativa in cui andrà inserito il pivot una volta ordinata la lista
          ;       R4 = Registro che contiene il valore del pivot
          ;       R5 = Registro che contiene progressivamente i valori da confrontare con il pivot
          ;       R7 = Registro d'appoggio

QUICKSORT STR     R0, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R1, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R8, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R2, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R3, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R4, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R5, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R7, [R13, #-4]!

          LDR     R0, [R13, #32]

          ;       Viene azzerato il contenuto dei registri che non vengono inizialmente sovrascritti
          MOV     R1, #0
          MOV     R2, #0
          MOV     R3, #0
          MOV     R8, #0

          ;       Converto la lunghezza della lista come multiplo di 4
CONV      ADD     R1, R1, #4
          SUB     R0, R0, #1
          CMP     R0, #1
          BGT     CONV

          LDR     R0, [R13, #36]

Q_SORT    STR     LR, [R13, #-4]!

          CMP     R8, R1
          BGE     SORTED

          MOV     R7, R1
LENGTH    ADD     R2, R2, #4
          SUB     R7, R7, #4
          CMP     R8, R7
          BLT     LENGTH

          ADD     R3, R2, #4

          LDR     R4, [R0, R8]

          ;       Ciclo sulla lista
CYCLESRT  LDR     R5, [R0, R2] ; Carico in R5 il valore dell'array all'indirizzo R0+[R2]

          CMP     R2, R8 ; Quando si è raggiunta la posizione del pivot si termina il ciclo e si passa in "SW_PIV"
          BLE     SW_PIV

          CMP     R5, R4 ; Se il valore contenuto in R5 > R4 salta in SWITCH
          BGT     SWITCH

          ADD     R2, R2, #-4 ; Si aggiorna lo spiazzamento
          B       CYCLESRT

          ;       Blocco in cui si effettua lo scambio di due valori
SWITCH    SUB     R3, R3, #4 ; Si aggiorna la posizione del pivot al valore precedente

          ;       Blocco in cui viene effettuato lo scambio dei due valori
          LDR     R7, [R0, R3] ; Si inserisce il valore che si trova all'indirizzo R0+[R3] in R7
          STR     R5, [R0, R3] ; Si inserisce il valore di R5 all'indirizzo R0+[R3]
          STR     R7, [R0, R2] ; Si inserisce il valore di R7 all'indirizzo R0+[R2]

          SUB     R2, R2, #4 ; Si aggiorna lo spiazzamento
          B       CYCLESRT


          ;       Blocco in cui ci si entra una volta aver ordinato tutta la lista tranne che il pivot. Viene switchato il pivot con il primo elemento
          ;       minore o uguale in modo tale che il pivot prenda la sua posizione finale all'interno dell'array.
SW_PIV    SUB     R3, R3, #4

          LDR     R7, [R0, R3]
          STR     R4, [R0, R3]
          STR     R7, [R0, R8]

          STR     R3, [R13, #-4]!
          STR     R1, [R13, #-4]!

LEFT      SUB     R1, R3, #4
          BL      Q_SORT

RIGHT     LDR     R1, [R13], #4
          LDR     R3, [R13], #4

          ADD     R2, R3, #4

          MOV     R8, R2

          BL      Q_SORT

SORTED    LDR     PC, [R13], #4


          ;       AREA DATI
LIST      DCD     4, -23, 3, 4, 12, 54
LEN       DCD     6
```

The correct code should finish with the final pop inside the subroutine "Quick sort" of the registers that I've used

Comment: There is no instructions that are armv7 specific.  It will work on any ARM CPU from late 90s onward.  Ie, at least ARMv4 and possibly earlier.  The code is using recursion, but does not [save the link register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer).